# How do I use Worker with app router in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, web-worker

I am attempting to use Worker in app router for Next.js, but so far not getting expected results. Essentially this is the code:

```
import Worker from 'web-worker';

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const worker = new Worker(`data:application/javascript,postMessage(42)`, {type:'module'});
  worker.addEventListener('message', e => {
      console.log("HAAAAAALLLLLOOOOOO! " + e.data)  // "200 OK"
  });
  worker.postMessage('hello');    

  return new Response('yada');
}
```

The expected output is: "HAAAAAALLLLLOOOOOO! 42", but it prints nothing when I try to "GET".

Attempting the same thing in pure node like this:

```
var Worker = require("web-worker")

const worker = new Worker(`data:application/javascript,postMessage(42)`);
worker.addEventListener('message', e => {
    console.log("HAAAAAALLLLLOOOOOO! " + e.data)
});
worker.postMessage('hello');
```

works as expected.

Here's a link to a repro repository: https://github.com/fursund/nextjs-web-worker-app-router-issue

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!